# Keyboard and mouse failure after update 18.04

Tags: gnome, updates, keyboard, mouse, 18.04

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a HP EliteBook 850 G3.  I just did an update in Gnome and restarted.  Everything works fine in the login screen, but as soon as I reach the desktop, the keyboard and mouse-clicks do not register. I turned the computer off, and logged in successfully in the Unity environment.  I tried "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall", then I restarted and again tried to boot in Gnome.  The problem persisted.  I also tried enabling the onscreen keyboard at the login screen, but it would not activate in gnome.  Any suggestions?

Comment: SOLVED- 
See https://github.com/passingthru67/workspaces-to-dock/issues/134
The issue was with the Gnome shell extension 'workspaces-to-dock'.  I logged into the Unity environment, and removed the following folder: 'Home/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com'.  I then restarted the computer and logged into gnome.  This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@AFC

Hi there, I'm suffering the same issue in an Ubuntu environment. Gnome 3.28.2 is installed, but I do not get access to any input. Mouse movement will be captured but no clicks and no keyboard entry.

Here is my fix:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

which actually installed gnome 3.28.3 and now I can access my GUI again.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is because of Xserver module lost，I fix it by this：
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> into the tty mode
and

```
 sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```